# datatable rows calculation using jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this table

| debit | credit | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0 |  |
| 100 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 150 |  |
| 0 | 200 |  |
| 200 | 0 |  |

I want the following balance column using datatable jquery or api .Please help me. Thanks in advance.

| debit | credit | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0 | 100 |
| 100 | 0 | 200 |
| 0 | 150 | 50 |
| 0 | 200 | -150 |
| 200 | 0 | 50 |

Comment: Hello, Swadhin and Welcome to StackOverflow! For future questions, try to provide [Minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): If we can copy/paste it into our machine, it's good! 
Then, make sure the title is a question, it clarifies the problem and makes it searchable. For example: how to sum two columns in Jquery? To which google answers (it might be your solution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802244/sum-total-for-column-in-jquery Nevertheless, your question is clear! You should look for jquery documentation https://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each row in the table's body with

```
$('#balance_table > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
}
```

Loop through each column in the current row with

```
cols.each(function(index, val) {
}
```

Write sum in the last column.

Demo:

```js
var sum = 0;

$('#balance_table > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
  var cols = $(this).find('td');
  cols.each(function(index, val) {
    // sum all columns except last column (balance)
    var isLast = index == cols.length - 1;
    var isDebit = index == 0;
    var isCredit = index == 1;
    if (isLast) {
      // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980821/jquery-each-method-obscures-this-keyword
      var jQueryObject = $(val);
      jQueryObject.text(sum);
    } else {
      sign = isCredit ? -1 : 1;
      sum += sign * parseFloat(val.textContent);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  background-color: gray;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="balance_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>debit</td>
      <td>credit</td>
      <td>balance</td>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See also:

- [jQuery each loop in table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431987/jquery-each-loop-in-table-row)
- [Sum values of a table column using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166972/sum-values-of-a-table-column-using-jquery)
- [jQuery sum the values of table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268900/jquery-sum-the-values-of-table-rows)
- [jQuery: selecting each td in a tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996521/jquery-selecting-each-td-in-a-tr)
- [Check for last iteration in jQuery.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393714/check-for-last-iteration-in-jquery-each)
- [Jquery $().each method obscures 'this' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980821/jquery-each-method-obscures-this-keyword)

Hope this helps!